Pg - Next js 15 Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
I am using next js 15 and drizzle orm. I have just added drizzle and setup the boilerplate and when i run it i get this error.
Error:
GET /_next/static/webpack/f2b54d6051787b9b.webpack.hot-update.json 500 in 20249ms
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 GET /dashboard 500 in 12048ms
 GET /favicon.ico 500 in 34ms
 ⨯ ./node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js:76:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
  74 |
  75 |   // Only try to load fs if we expect to read from the disk
> 76 |   const fs = config.sslcert || config.sslkey || config.sslrootcert ? require('fs') : null
     | ^
  77 |
  78 |   if (config.sslcert) {
  79 |     config.ssl.cert = fs.readFileSync(config.sslcert).toString()      

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found


db file for drizzle
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/node-postgres";
import { Pool } from "pg";
import { schema } from "@/schema";
import { env } from "@/config/env";


export const client = new Pool({
  connectionString: env.DATABASE_URL,
});

export const db = drizzle(client, { schema, casing: "snake_case" });


Drizzle Configuration file
import { defineConfig, Config } from "drizzle-kit";
import "dotenv";

export default defineConfig({
  dialect: "postgresql",
  schema: "./schema/*",
  dbCredentials: {
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL!,
  },
  verbose: true,
  strict: true,
  out: "./drizzle/migrations",
  casing: "snake_case",
} as Config);

I even tried changing the client from pg to postgress but i kept getting these module missing errors (some times it shows net module missing).

The modules like fs can be used only on server side. Make sure you are not importing anything on client side from any file that has server side only code.
